# Sampling rate versus number of sample of I and Q

Tags: sampling, qpsk

I am acquiring data of an O-QPSK signal (chip rate : 2Mchip/s) with a SDR. I am undersampling the signal at 20 Mhz (carrier is at 2.8 GHz) so I respect the Shannon-Nyquist criterion that you need to sample 2 time the bandwidth of your signal, however when I take apart the I and Q phase, the signal look like it has been sampled at 10 Mhz. I observe this when I create my reference signal in matlab with a sampling rate of 20 Mhz for each phase I&Q. I end up with a signal x2 time the size of the real signal (2560 samples vs 5120 samples).

The chip period of my signal is 1 microsecond and I am sampling at a rate of a rate of 20 Mhz  with 128 in my sampling period, you effectively end up with 2560 samples.

When you take each phase alone, each part of a chip will be 2 time the period chip which result in a signal of 2 microsecond, therefore is we don't divide the sampling rate by 2, we will end with 5120 sample.

This effect seem to be produce by the phase offset that the O-QPSK use. Can someone give an explanation about this phenomenon?

[EDIT]

The SDR I am using is the B200 Mini from Ettus Research.

Comment: wait, why do you think the signal is undersampled?

Comment: i.e. what's the bandwidth you're observing? most SDR frontends I'm aware of won't allow you to undersample without intrusive modification of the driver.

Comment: are these 20 million complex equivalent baseband samples per second, or are are these 20 million real-valued samples from some superhet receiver?

Comment: How exactly are you recording? Command lines / device configurations and the actual device you use might be helpful!

Comment: @MarcusMüller undersampling, well the highest frequency of my signal was 2.4GHz + Bandwitdh. Sampling at 20Mhz don't respect the Nyquist theorem but it respect the Shannon-Nyquist theorem. I use the b200 mini USRP

Comment: @MarcusMüller The set up is just a GNU Radio UHD driver that feed its data into a file sink which is then used with Matlab

Comment: @MarcusMüller from where the data come? I sincerely don't know the B200 mini is pretty much a black box to me

Comment: You're misunderstanding the B200! It is a direct conversion receiver! That means that it first mixes 2.4GHz to 0Hz, and then digitizes the resulting 0Hz+-Bandwidth. You're not doing undersampling in any shape. In fact, odds are that the B200mini is configured to significantly oversample (x4, Master Clock Rate=40MHz) the signal and internally filter and decimate to your requested sampling rate (10MHz).

Comment: Are you sure your Matlab script is interpreting the data in the file correctly? Those are complex samples, i.e. one float real, one float imag for each sample.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am pretty sure the matlab script is correct. We are using read_complex_binary from the gnuradio repositery

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you know any document for the interl architecture of the b200? Because right now the B200 seem like a black box to me

Comment: well, the datasheet from the [product page](https://www.ettus.com/product/details/USRP-B200mini) contains a schematic that shows the IQ complex baseband lines.

Comment: regarding the matlab script: and you're also interpreting the output of `read_complex_binary` as complex, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes I use the data as a comples stream

Comment: Then there's something wrong somewhere else in your code. Getting samples for a duration $t$ at a sampling rate of $f_s$ will yield exactly $N=tf_s$ samples.